# Layout Update for adminhtml page

Tags: adminhtml, tabs, layout-update

I have two customer attribute that I would like to display on the "Customer view" Tab in Magento admin. I have been able to display the values from the attribute but adding:

```
   <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $this->__('Customer attribute:') ?></strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getCutomerAttribute()) ?></td>
    </tr>
```

To `adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml` file. The problem is I'd prefer not to directly edit this template file and have been looking for a way to add my template without touching the default.

I have tried to add a local.xml file to override the default template but it's not working correctly...

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit" name="customer_edit"></block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="adminhtml/template" name="optional_zip_countries" as="optional_zip_countries" template="directory/js/optional_zip_countries.phtml" />
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/product/composite/configure.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>varien/configurable.js</file></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tabs" name="customer_edit_tabs">
                <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view" name="customer_edit_tab_view" template="path/to/customer/tab/view.phtml">
                    <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_sales" name="sales" template="customer/tab/view/sales.phtml" before="-" />
                    <block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_accordion" name="accordion" />
                </block>
                <action method="addTab"><name>customer_edit_tab_view</name><block>customer_edit_tab_view</block></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

</adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

I've also tried to use a layout update inside of my module but I kept getting errors

```
"Mage registry key "subscriber" already exists";i:1;s:2926:"#0
```

And then..

```
  Wrong tab configuration
```

when I tried to rewrite the block class

I'm now running out of ideas and could do with some help here please...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be able to do is using the following xml set the template of the view tab:

```
<adminhtml_customer_edit>
    <reference name="customer_edit_tab_view">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>your/template/file.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_customer_edit>
```

Comment: Excellent, thankyou for your assistance!

Comment: can you show the file please